# Repeat a set of tests for different conditions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I would like to a repeat set of unit tests, having the same setup fixture (`SetUpFixture`), for different conditions.

i.e. set of tests use the same file as an input. The file is being set in the setup fixture. I would like to repeat the tests that use the set up fixture for different input file.

It's possible for `TextFixture`, but not for `SetupFixture`. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to generate few input files and use the file name as a parameter for your test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClass
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    //[OneTimeSetUp] for NUnit 3
    public void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        PrepareFile("a.txt");
        PrepareFile("b.txt");
        PrepareFile("c.txt");
    }

    [TestCase("a.txt")]
    [TestCase("b.txt")]
    [TestCase("c.txt")]
    public void Test(string fileName)
    {
        var result = YourTestCode(fileName);
        Assert.True(result); //whatever you need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TestFixtureAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) to construct your test class with each data file. Migrating Anton's answer;

```
[TestFixture("a.txt")]
[TestFixture("b.txt")]
[TestFixture("c.txt")]
public class MyClass
{
    string _filename;

    public MyClass(string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
    }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    //[OneTimeSetUp] for NUnit 3
    public void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        PrepareFile(_filename);
    }

    [Test()]
    public void Test()
    {
        var result = YourTestCode();
        Assert.True(result); //whatever you need
    }
}
```

If you want a more dynamic way you provide the data for the TestFixture, look at the  [TestFixtureSourceAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureSource-Attribute)

Comment: Yep, that's even better

Comment: Yeap, that's what I've mentioned exists in NUnit. It's not possible for SetupFixture I'm using. :(

Comment: The SetupFixture provides global run-once SetUp and TearDown for all the tests in the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am pretty sure that we don't have anything in NUnit that can be used for that. I assume that if that was the case that you would want to run all of your test fixtures once for each of those assembly setups?

Comment: That's right, whole set of test would be repeated several times.

Comment: Feel free to add a feature request to our GitHub repo for NUnit and I will start the discussion. No guarantees when/if it will be implemented, but requests carry more weight coming from users ;)